# Looping through JSON objects in a Kendo JavaScript Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-window

I am trying to figure out how I can create a Kendo template that will loop through a JSON array returned by an AJAX request. Here is what the data object look likes:

```
[{"Id":5, "CreatedBy":"testuser1"},
{"Id":6,"Archived":false,"CreatedBy":"testuser2"},
{"Id":7,"Archived":false,"CreatedBy":"testuser3"}]
```

I would like to list just the CreatedBy field like this in a [Kendo template](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/templates/expressions):

Users List:
testuser1
testuser2
testuser3

Here is my attempt and it is not working:

```
<ul>
     # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
          <li>#= data[i].CreatedBy #</li>
     # } #
</ul>
```

I just get a listing of undefined, undefined, undefined...
and when I remove CreatedBy and just do data[i] I get each letter of each field listed. How do I access the actual CreatedBy values from the data object?

Comment: is your object an array, or {data: [{}, {}, {}]}?

Comment: My object that is getting returned from the AJAX request looks exactly how I show it at the top of my post when I output it to the browser in an alert. Please see the answer I just posted, I guess I figured it out because it is working. Parsing the json to a JavaScript array helped me loop through it easier.

Comment: glad that you solved your own problem :)  
Did you set the dataType of AJAX to JSON? It seems to me your data return is a string but not JSON.  If that's the case, you can set the dataType of the request, so that you don't need to parseJSON explicitly

Comment: Hmm so what I posted above as an example of what the ajax request is returning isn't JSON? It looks like it to me. I will specify the dataType to be JSON and see if it changes.

Comment: Yea it's a wild guess based on: 1. OP data[i].CreatedBy Undefined  2. OP data[i] will show each character (like a string)  3. After $.parseJSON, it works

Comment: You were exactly right I was able to do the following: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-content.template. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted by parsing it first. If anyone else has a better cleaner way of doing it please let me know.

```
<script id="myKendoTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <ul style="list-style: none; padding: 0;">
        # var objList = $.parseJSON(data); #
        # for (var i = 0; i < objList.length; i++) { #
            <li>#= objList[i].CreatedBy #</li>
       # } #
    </ul>
</script>
```

If anyone is interested another update is that I found this in the [kendo window documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-content.template). If you set dataType to json the data gets parsed by jQuery for you and you don't need the $.parseJSON(data) line.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, the problem is due to the dataType of the AJAX request.

By default the return data type is string, which cannot parsed by Kendo Template.

After explicitly specified the  `dataType: "json"` in the request, or like OP's own answer which parse the return data to JSON type, it can be understood by Kendo Template and act normal again.